# Harmonic progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three unequal numbers are in Harmonic Progression and their squares are in Arithmetic progression. Prove that the numbers are in the ratio  1-3^1/2:-2:1+3^1/2

Comment: You've already tried doing anything for this problem? That should be included in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Three numbers are in harmonic progression if their reciprocals are in arithmetic progression.  Call the numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$, with the "middle" one being $y$.
Our harmonic progression requirement can be written as
$$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{y}$$
(the difference of successive reciprocals is constant).

Because the squares are in arithmetic progression, we have
$$y^2-x^2=z^2-y^2.$$
We can choose one of the numbers almost arbitrarily. So let $y=1$. (If you don't like this, you can keep $y$. If we want to get the answer as given directly, let $y=-2$.)
With a little simplification, our two equations can be written as
$$2xz=x+z \qquad\text{and}\qquad x^2+z^2=2.$$
Now we need to solve for $x$ and $z$. There are various approaches. We use one that is useful elsewhere.

Let $p=xz$ and $s=x+z$. Here $p$ of course stands for product, and $s$ stands for sum.

The first equation is simply $2p=s$. For the second equation, use $x^2+z^2=(x+z)^2-2xz=s^2-2p$. So the second equation is $s^2-2p=2$. But $2p=s$. Substituting, we get $s^2-s-2=0$. This is easy to solve for $s$.  We get $s=-1$ or $s=2$.

Suppose first that $s=-1$. Then $p=-\frac{1}{2}$. So $x$ and $z$ satisfy the quadratic equation
$$w^2+w-\frac{1}{2}.$$ 
Solve. We get
$$w=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
This gives the ratios
$$\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}:1:\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Multiply by $-2$ and reverse the order to get the answer asked for.

Finally, look at the possibility $s=2$. That gives $p=1$, and fairly quickly $x=z$, contradicting the requirement of distinctness.